# Unable to read the cookie set with HostOnly=true and HttpOnly=true options using PHP $_COOKIE

Tags: php, cookies, single-sign-on, httpcookie

How do we read the cookie set with HostOnly=true and HttpOnly=true options using PHP $_COOKIE. This cookie is set via Single Sign On method.

[image]

I tried by using the below code but it is not capturing the cookie set with set with HostOnly=true and HttpOnly=true options.
Please suggest me, how I can read this type of cookie information using PHP. Thanks in advance.

PHP Code:

```
protected function cookieString() {
    $string = '';
    foreach ($_COOKIE as $k => $v) {
        $k = urlencode($k);
        if ($string) $string .= "; $k=$v";
        else $string .= "$k=$v";
    }
    
    return $string;
}
```

Also I am attaching a rough figure of our application architecture below:
[image]

Comment: I had a similar problem once ago, but there is no solution. Only cookie names and values are sent to the server.

Comment: `HostOnly` means that request's host must exactly match the domain of the cookie ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies/Cookie#Type)). Do they match?

Comment: Yes, it is. One thing I noticed that, those cookie information I am able to see from the browser 'Inspect Element' Tool. But unable to read it from the application servers using $_COOKIE php global variable

Comment: In the browser tools ("Network" pane), can you see the cookie headers being added to HTTP requests?

Comment: Yes Alvaro, I am able to see all the cookies in the browser tools ("Network" pane)

Comment: As you can see there, the [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) header doesn't even contain host or path info. PHP has no way to handle such cookies in a different way. The error must be somewhere else. I see you've added a graph that shows quite a complex set up. I'd say some of the proxies are stripping the cookies.